# Checking radio boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering is it possible to have a radiobox checkgroup just 1 on load? Only using JavaScript not using `check=checked` in html? I only know that. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

E.G

```
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Phone" id="RadioGroup1_0"    />Phone</label>

<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Email" id="RadioGroup1_1" />Email</label>

<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Mail" id="RadioGroup1_2" />Mail</label>
```

Comment: Why did you want like that?

Comment: @KiranRS I just thought it'd be more professional and it would validate in W3C as im coding it in XHTML 1.0

Comment: I don't know its "proffessionality" ,but in my point of view, we should minimize the java script in order to page load faster.

Comment: Actually it would be much less professional and showing that you don't understand how to do things properly and quality. Don't care about W3C validation so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
document.querySelector("#RadioGroup1_0").click();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uk6cD/

May be it is relevant for you to wrap it in the window' `load` event handler:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.querySelector("#RadioGroup1_0").click();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working when I put it in with my code? Any suggestion?

Comment: @user3554003 do you see some errors in the console?

Comment: Have a look at my JSFIDDLE, it works when I input it there but for some reason when I transfer it to notepad++ and either open Chrome/Firefox doesn't seem to work?  http://jsfiddle.net/uk6cD/3/

Comment: @user3554003 did you try to use it with the `window.onload` ?

Comment: Yes I did try and use window.onload. No luck :(

Comment: I've managed to fix it, thanks a lot! It was window.onload. :P

Comment: Note that this code will not work on IE7, which is still in use by about 5% of internet users.

Answer (score 0):

This may help,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#RadioGroup1_0").attr('checked','checked');
});
```

Comment: Have a look at my JSFIDDLE, it works when I input it there but for some reason when I transfer it to notepad++ and either open Chrome/Firefox doesn't seem to work? jsfiddle.net/uk6cD/3

Comment: you have errors in html parts, did you check your tags, opening/ closing html,head,body...

Comment: Everything is closed the way it should be it works in JSFIDDLE but not when i transfer it to notepad++ and open it with chrome/firefox :/

Comment: Sorry, but when i check jsfiddle,i didn't see `<html><head></head>` parts. it starts with `<body>`

Comment: Yes, jsfiddle only accepts html code and java. Not the whole thing